# Postgresql Row Level Security Checking new data in WITH CHECK in Policy for INSERT

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I've a Database with several tables.
A user has several objects and an object has several parts.

I want to write a policy that only the creator of the object is allowed to add parts to the object. Therefore I need to get the object a to be inserted part belongs to, but I've no idea how to check the data.

Is there a way to get the data to be inserted in the policy?

Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how to implement something like that with row level security. Adapt it to your need!

```
CREATE TABLE object(
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name text NOT NULL,
   owner name NOT NULL DEFAULT current_user
);

CREATE TABLE part(
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   parent_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES object(id),
   name text NOT NULL
);
```

We have to give people some permissions:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON object TO PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON part TO PUBLIC;
```

Now we enable row level security and allow only `INSERT`s in `part` when the `owner` in `object` matches:

```
ALTER TABLE part ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY insert_only_owned ON part
   FOR INSERT TO PUBLIC
   WITH CHECK (EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM object o
                  WHERE o.id = parent_id
                    AND owner = current_user
              ));
```

Comment: is it important that `ALTER TABLE part ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY` should come after `GRANT`?

Comment: answer on my question is NO